# handling a few large bson documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a little more than one million JSON documents that I want to insert in a MongoDB collection.  The collection is very stable (no insertion, no deletion) but need to be queried a lot.  The problem is that 12 of these documents are larger than 16MB and are rejected.

I have looked at the GridFS documentation but it seems that with GridFS documents are considered as binary files that can be stored as chunks but not queried.  If possible, I would also like to avoid splitting documents and storing them in separate collections since it makes queries unnecessarily complex (i.e., query collections separately and program a join between them) in most of the case - I only have 12 problematic documents.

Is there a recommended way to deal with this?  Is there a way to relax the 16MB limit?

Comment: What kind of data are you storing? The 16mb limit is in place for system stability there's (intentionally) no workaround. A side-effect of the 16mb limit is the need to rethink your collection strategy. For only 12 documents out of one million. Perhaps you could, leave them out, split them up, or reduce their overall size by stripping out unnecessary information.

Comment: In this case, I think going over the 16MB limit would be OK.  I mainly use MongoDB to explore this data set, not to store it or manage it in a particular way.  However, I have inserted the documents that fit and I keep the 12 large ones separate.  Now I have to find another way to deal with them.

Comment: There's a JIRA ticket with a lot of argument out there about raising the limit from its previous 4mb to 16mb. If you have the patience to read through it there's some good learning as to why its there.